# Can not upload files when running tests in docker Selenium_Hub, Selenium-Node-Chrome-Debug and a container w/ Mocha + Selenium-Webdriver (JS)

Tags: node.js, docker, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I have spent a lot of time experimenting and using google trying to find a solution to this issue but I have not had any success and I am hoping that someone will be able to provide some guidance. So here is my situation, I am trying to run javascript mocha selenium-webdriver tests on my company's application using docker containers.  I seem to have everything working except that I am unable to upload files.  Prior to trying use my tests in a docker environment I was able to use it on our local servers and upload files with no issue using the a method like this:

```
        const companyImage = process.cwd()+ '/img/backgroundmario.jpg';
        const companyImageElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[@type='file']"));
        await companyImageElem.sendKeys(companyImage);
```

However, I have not been able to have any success when using docker containers.  I mounted my img folder to my selenium/node-chrome-debug container which includes a VNC viewer and I can see that the images are present (and I can manually upload the images via the VNC viewer).  However, despite numerous variations of providing paths to the images I can not seem to get my images to upload.  For some reason the working directory seems to be from my test container and not my node-chrome-debug container but even if I add the images to the test container and change the path to my test container directory with the images they do not upload either.

Here is a snippet of my code I am using for my test (it includes some stuff I wouldn't normally include, specifically the check for process.cwd() and process.env.PWD since I just wanted to see what the path was:

```
const {
   Builder,
   By,
   Key,
   until,
   webdriver,
   action
} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const mocha = require('mocha');
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
const {
   makeUtilityBelt
} = require('./util')
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const fs = require('fs');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const ciPassword = require('./envData').ciPassword;
const campManagerMail  = 'jdrzymala+companycreator@influential.co';
const campManagerName = 'companycreator';
const campManagerUsername = 'companycreator';
const legacy = "http://node-web-client";
const companyImage = '/opt/test/images/backgroundmario.jpg';
var currentDir = process.cwd();
var appFolder = process.env.PWD;
const {
   createLegacyAdmin,
   createLegacyResellerCompany,
   createLegacyBrandCompany,
   createLegacyAgencyCompany,
   createLegacyCampManager,
   createLegacyClient,
   createLegacyInfluencer
} = require('./legacyCreationQueries');
const {
   getEmailId,
   getUserEmailId,
   getRandom,
   verifyRandom,
   accountSetup
} = require('./sqlutil');

describe('Creates a Company of Each Type via the Legacy Dashboard', function () {
   this.timeout(1200000);
   this.slow(20000);
   let driver;
   let util;

   before(async function () {
       driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').usingServer('http://selenium_hub:4444/wd/hub').build();
       util = makeUtilityBelt(driver);
       await createLegacyCampManager(campManagerName, campManagerUsername, campManagerMail);

   });
   afterEach(function () {
       let testCaseName = this.currentTest.title;
       let testCaseStatus = this.currentTest.state;
       if (testCaseStatus === 'failed') {
           driver.takeScreenshot().then((data) => {
               let screenshotPath = `./results/${testCaseName}.png`;
               console.log(`Saving Screenshot as: ${screenshotPath}`);
               fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath, data, 'base64');
           });
       } 
   });
   after(function () {
       driver.quit();
   });
   describe('Load Legacy Corporate Site and Login to Legacy Dashboard', function () {

       it('Loads into the Legacy Dashboard Successfully', async function () {
           await driver.get(legacy);
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Sign In')]"), 10000));
           await driver.sleep(3000);
           const emailElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"));
           await util.sendKeys(emailElem, campManagerMail);
           const pwElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']"));
           await util.sendKeys(pwElem, ciPassword);
           await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).click();
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//div/ul[contains(@class, 'campaign-search-list')]"), 10000));
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(),'User Management')]"), 10000));
           await driver.sleep(5000);
           await console.log("Below is the Current Working Directory");
           await console.log(currentDir);
           await driver.sleep(3000);
           await console.log(appFolder);
           await driver.sleep(3000);
           await console.log("The above is the app folder");
           await driver.sleep(2000);
           const loginSuccessElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(),'User Management')]"));
           let loginSuccess = await loginSuccessElem.isDisplayed();
           await driver.sleep(3000);
           await expect(loginSuccess, 'Legacy Login Failed').to.be.true;
       });
   });
   describe('Creates a Reseller Company', function(){
       const companyName = 'Reseller Test Company';
       it('Navigates to Company Management and Begins Company Creation Process', async function(){
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(),'Company Management')]"), 10000));
           await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='menu']/li/a/span[contains(text(),'Company Management')]")).click();
           await driver.sleep(8000);
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Search Companies')]"), 10000));
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'+ Create Company')]"), 10000));
           await driver.sleep(8000);
           await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'+ Create Company')]")).click();
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Create Company')]"), 10000));
           const companyCreationPageElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Create Company')]"));
           let companyCreationPage = await companyCreationPageElem.isDisplayed();
           await expect(companyCreationPage, 'Company Creation Page failed to Load').to.be.true;            
       });
       it('Fills in the required fields and creates New Reseller Company', async function(){            
           const companyDescription = 'This is a test description for a random test company blah blah blah';
           const companyAddress = '777 Lucky Lane';
           const companyCity = 'Las Vegas';
           const companyState = 'Nevada';
           const companyZip = '89104';
           const companyNameElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@label='Company Name']"));
           await util.sendKeys(companyNameElem, companyName);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const companyDescriptionElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@label='Company Description']"));
           await util.sendKeys(companyDescriptionElem, companyDescription);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const companyTypeElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"));
           await companyTypeElem.click();
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//select/option"), 10000));
           const companyTypeSelectElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select/option[@value='1']"));
           await companyTypeSelectElem.click();
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const addressElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@label='Address']"));
           await util.sendKeys(addressElem, companyAddress);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const cityElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@label='City']"));
           await util.sendKeys(cityElem, companyCity);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const stateElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@label='State']"));
           await util.sendKeys(stateElem, companyState);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const zipElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@label='Zip Code']"));
           await util.sendKeys(zipElem, companyZip);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(companyImage);
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//img[@class='image-preview']"), 10000));
           await driver.sleep(1000);
           const submitButtonElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]"));
           await submitButtonElem.click();
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Company Actions')]"), 10000));
           await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//p[@class='company-name']"), 10000));
           const companySuccessElem = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='company-name'][contains(text(),'"+companyName+"')]"));
           let companySuccess = await companySuccessElem.isDisplayed();
           await expect(companySuccess, 'Failed to Create New Company').to.be.true;
       });
   });
});
```

This is the last thing stopping me from integrating my large number of test files with our CI/CD process but a huge number of my tests involve uploading files so it is a major issue.  I am extremely thankful for any guidance anyone could provide me.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Despite not receiving any guidance here, with a bit of additional research, the assistance of a coworker and some experimentation I was able to solve my problem.

So there are several aspects that are important.  First of all, you must make sure that the images you want to upload are mounted to the container with your browser (in my case, selenium/node-chrome-debug).  Then you must make some additions to your test Selenium test file.

You must add the following lines:

```
var path = require('path');
var remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
```

You can use **var** or let although I've been told that **let** is a better standard practice.

Then, after the line

```
driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').usingServer('http://selenium_hub:4444/wd/hub').build();
```

Add this line of code

```
driver.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
```

For your the file you wish to upload, you must set the path to that of the file system on the browser container (selenium/node-chrome-debug in my case).  So your file variable would be something like:

```
const companyImage = process.cwd()+'/images/backgroundmario.jpg';
```

Then, when you want to upload the file, you find the respective element using whichever form of identification you like and add a little extra to the sendKeys function in comparison to how you would do it were you simply running the script on your local file system rather than a docker container.  So the code would look like this:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(path.resolve(__dirname, companyImage));
```

Maybe there is a slightly cleaner way to code it (for example, I generally declare the elements I am interacting with as variables) but the example I have provided will work.  It took me a lot of time and effort to find this solution so I hope this eventually saves someone else the amount of pain I experienced trying to get this to work.